# How to convert a flat data structure into a tree-like structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

Let's say I have two helper functions converting flat array of {} into tree-like structure. Consider the following flat data:

```
const data = [
     {
            "ID": 1,
            "Tier_1": "DataSource1",
            "Tier_2": "Area",
            "Tier_3": "General",
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "Tier_1": "DataSource1",
            "Tier_2": "Financial",
            "Tier_3": "General",
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "Tier_1": "DataSource1",
            "Tier_2": "Area",
            "Tier_3": "General",
        },
        {
            "ID": 4,
            "Tier_1": "DataSource2",
            "Tier_2": "Area",
            "Tier_3": "General",
        },
        {
            "ID": 5,
            "Tier_1": "DataSource2",
            "Tier_2": "Area",
            "Tier_3": "Management Plan",
        }
]
```

The data contains three rows of some hierarchical information, that I would like to convert into tree-like structure, like this (expected output):

(Last children are actual DB objects, but distributed on tree)

```
const output = {
  "DataSource1: {
    "Area": {
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "Tier_1": "DataSource1",
            "Tier_2": "Area",
            "Tier_3": "General",
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "Tier_1": "DataSource1",
            "Tier_2": "Area",
            "Tier_3": "General",
        },
      },
      "Financial": [
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "Tier_1": "DataSource1",
            "Tier_2": "Financial",
            "Tier_3": "General",
        },
      ]
  },
  "DataSource2: {
      "Area": [
          {
            "ID": 4,
            "Tier_1": "DataSource2",
            "Tier_2": "Area",
            "Tier_3": "General",
          },
          {
            "ID": 5,
            "Tier_1": "DataSource2",
            "Tier_2": "Area",
            "Tier_3": "Management Plan",
          }
       ]
      }
  }
}
```

I actually managed to create functions to do accomplish this, but I they are not so flexible (the depth / dim is fixed, which is stated in each function name)

Function returning 2-dimensional tree:

```
const getDataCategoriesTwoDim = (data, mainCategory) => {
  const dataFields = [...data];
  let map = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < dataFields.length; i += 1) {
    const currentField = dataFields[i];
    const currentCategory = currentField[mainCategory];

    if (!map[currentCategory]) {
      map[currentCategory] = [];
    }
    map[currentCategory].push(currentField);
  }

  return map;
};
```

Function returning three-dimension tree:

```
const getDataCategoriesThreeDim = (data, mainCategory, subCategory) => { // DIFF
  const dataFields = [...data];
  let map = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < dataFields.length; i += 1) {
    const currentField = dataFields[i];
    const currentCategory = currentField[mainCategory];
    const currentSubcategory = currentField[subCategory]; // DIFF

    if (!map[currentCategory]) {
      map[currentCategory] = {}; /DIFF
    }
    if (!map[currentCategory][currentSubcategory]) { // DIFF
      map[currentCategory][currentSubcategory] = []; // DIFF
    } // DIFF
    map[currentCategory][currentSubcategory].push(currentField); // DIFF
  }

  return map;
};
```

You can call both like this and get expected result:

```
  getDataCategoriesTwoDim(data, 'Tier_2');
  getDataCategoriesThreeDim(data, 'Tier_2', 'Tier_3');
```

As you can see, there is so much code repetition and copy paste. I marked differences in comments. How could I rewrite the code into one function, so that I can set 2, 3 or more dimensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the keys for nesting properties and add an array for the last key instead of an object. Later push the object to the nested array.

```js
const
    groupBy = (data, keys) => data.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys
            .reduce((p, k, i, a) =>
                 p[o[k]] = p[o[k]] || (i + 1 === a.length ? [] : {}), r)
            .push(o);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)),
    data = [{ ID: 1, Tier_1: "DataSource1", Tier_2: "Area", Tier_3: "General" }, { ID: 2, Tier_1: "DataSource1", Tier_2: "Financial", Tier_3: "General" }, { ID: 3, Tier_1: "DataSource1", Tier_2: "Area", Tier_3: "General" }, { ID: 4, Tier_1: "DataSource2", Tier_2: "Area", Tier_3: "General" }, { ID: 5, Tier_1: "DataSource2", Tier_2: "Area", Tier_3: "Management Plan" }],
    result1 = groupBy(data, ["Tier_1", "Tier_2"]),
    result2 = groupBy(data, ["Tier_1", "Tier_2", "Tier_3"]);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey Nina! Short and elegant, simply awesome. Thank you

Comment: @Nina, Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to add another key along with the DataSource?
Ex : {name: "DataSource1, subItems : [ { name: "Area", subItems : [ ... ] } ] }
Basically, array of objects with a property name?